# Displaying only certain labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, fields-attributes, expression

I'd like to display all of polygons but only label some of them. Case would be: the value in row `"TabelleImp"` contains the word *'offen'*.

I thought these expressions might work, but I they don't:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "TabelleImp" IS NOT "%offen%" THEN NULL
    ELSE "TabelleImp"
END
```

or

```py
IF("TabelleImp" LIKE "%offen%", "TabelleImp", NULL)
```

Comment: Currently you're asking whether your attribute in the field `"TabelleImp"` equals the attribute in the field `"%offen%"` - which is not what you're trying to do. Trying using single quotation marks (`'`). Furthermore, I'd go with `regexp_match()` since it feels easier to me - but that is my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label your layer with the field `"TabelleImp"`, then in label settings go to the last tab `Rendering` and set a data driven override for `show label`, using this expression:

```
strpos("TabelleImp", 'offen')=0
```

or - alternatively, with the same result:

```
regexp_match("TabelleImp", 'offen')=0
```

---

To use it directly in the value field of the label, use this syntax and replace `[condition]` with one of the expressions from above:

```sql
case 
    when [condition] then "TabelleImp"
    ...
end
```

---

**Explanation**

The function [`stropos()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#strpos) finds the first matching position of the substring *'offen'* inside the input string (from the field `"TabelleImp"`) and returns it's position or 0 if no match is found.

The function [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches) works basically the same, but using regular expressions.

[image]